# Creating a file that is passed as an argument in C

Tags: c, fopen

I am writing a socket program, where the client sends a file to the server and the server stores the file name in a new location. My question is: when the client passes the file name to the server, how can I create a file using the same name in a new location. The file handler looks like this

```
fw=fopen("c://TestCopy","a+");
```

what do I need to do so that fopen takes the filename passed, to open the file.

Comment: What do you mean by "same name" and "new location"?

Comment: For eg.: the client program runs like this - ./client.exe 127.0.0.1 100 IOC-LOGO.jpg. The server needs to get the file name and store it with the same name in a new location.

Comment: This is still ambigous. What do you mean with "same" name and "new" location, specifically?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. The client program sends a file which the server receives and stores in the disk. The 3rd parameter of client is the file (IOC-LOGO.jpg in the example). The server receives the file (IOC-LOGO.jpg). But I want to rename this file at the server program, so that if there is another file with the same name, it is not over-written. I want to rename the file as well as store it at say, C:\Users\XYZ\TestNew.jpg

Comment: There are lots of factors involved here. You should try to get an idea of what specifically you need to know, then try to implement it yourself and come back with some code we can work with. As presented, this is "not a real question". Rule of thumb: If there's not even a question mark in the question, you should work on it a bit before posting it :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will work on it some more and get back. Can this be left open until then please?

Comment: Sarvavyapi: You can leave it as is, but I think that it might be closed. That's not a problem though, if you add more information later, it can be re-opened.

Comment: Thanks Niklas. I have now found the solution to my problem. I just had to use the rename() utility in C to move/rename the file I was transferring from the client to the server. I used ---> rename(tempName, name) -- to rename the temporary file to the actual name.

Comment: Nice work :) And you didn't even need our help!  Well done indeed.

Answer (score -1):

I'm just a bit confused here. I think what you want is this:

```
fw = fopen(argv[1], "r");

...

// send the filename
send(server, argv[1], strlen(argv[1]) + 1, 0);

...
```

Server:

```
... 

// receive the file name
int fileNameLen = recv(client, buffer, maxBufferSize, 0);

fopen(buffer, "w");

...
```

Comment: here, buffer gets the filename, which is used by fopen. But what is the path used by fopen? In other words, if argv[1] passed by client is C:\Temp\Test.txt, I want the same file stored at C:\Test.txt by the server

Comment: @Sarvavyapi then you need to find a way to make the string equal to the last path component, which is no easy matter if you want to do something cross-platform. I have answered the question you asked, so do some research on getting the path component.

Comment: @Richard: Sorry, I don't agree with you. The question is too ambiguous to make any assertions about whether it was answered by this answer or not. You shouldn't have answered in the first place if you didn't know what was asked. That's what comments are for.